# bash: mongodb/bin/mongod : No such file or directory

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu

I'm  trying to install and run some basic commands on `mongodb` from this [tutorial (on page 4)](http://openmymind.net/mongodb.pdf).

So far,

1. I've downloaded the a 32-bit zip file from the [mongodb download page](http://www.mongodb.org/downloads).
2. I've unzip the file in the following locations `home/user1` then renamed it to `mongodb`
3. I've create a folder called data then another one inside called db
4. I've created a file name mongodb.config containing the path of the folder where I want to store my data, which is `mongodb/data/db`.

But when I run the command to start the server:

```
user1@user1-VirtualBox: ~$ mongodb/bin/mongod --dbpath ~mongodb/data/db
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
bash: mongodb/bin/mongod : No such file or directory
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: How about add a dot  like: ./mongodb/bin/mongod --dbpath ~mongodb/data/db

Comment: Could you do a quick check and issue `which mongod`? And if this does not show a result, a `find ~/ -type f -name mongod`? And if this does not show you a location, a `sudo find / -type f -name mongod`?

Answer (score 0):

Missing a '/', it should be ~/mongodb/data/db, not '~mongodb/data/db'

Comment: Even though that is true the dbpath arg cannot actually take shortcuts like that it needs to taek the absolute path, i.e. `/home/user/mongodb/data/db`

Comment: adding `/` or add the entire path, I'm still getting the same error: `bash: mongodb/bin/mongod : No such file or directory`

Comment: @Richard77 have you checked you to see if your steps completed correctly. How about doing an ls -la in that directory your in.

Comment: 'cd' into the directory containing mongod, and then 'pwd' to get the full path. Use the full path instead of 'mongodb/bin/mongod'

Comment: I've `cd mongodb/bin`. Once inside, I've run `pwd` and got this: `/home/user1/mongodb/bin`

Comment: If the following cmd not working, then double check to make sure you downloaded the right zip (should it be a 64 bit?). user1@user1-VirtualBox: ~$ /home/user1/mongodb/bin --dbpath /home/user1/mongodb/data/db

Comment: I've run ` /home/user1/mongodb/bin/mongod --dbpath /home/user1/mongodb/data/db`, but I'm still getting the same error. When I try  mongod --dbpath /home/user1/mongodb/data/db`, I'm getting a new type of error: `The progtam 'mongodb' is not currently installed. You can install it by typing sudo apt-get install mongodb-server`

Comment: make sure you try 'mongod --dbpath /home/user1/mongodb/data/db' under the directory '/home/user1/mongodb/bin'